# SQLite trigger after update

Tags: sqlite

My table has timestamp column. I want a trigger which sets timestamp to 0 on affected rows when a row is updated and the timestamp is not specified in the update statement.

If I use this trigger:

```
CREATE TRIGGER AFTER UPDATE ON mytable FOR EACH ROW
WHEN (NEW.timestamp IS NULL)
BEGIN
UPDATE mytable SET timestamp = 0 WHERE id = NEW.id;
END;
```

then the trigger doesn't fire for this update statement:

```
UPDATE mytable SET comecolumn='some'
```

I.e. timestamp of affected rows doesn't change to 0.

Can you please help me define the trigger?

Comment: you trigger is not fired because of the `WHEN` statement if your timestamp is not `NULL`, when do you want it to be fired ?

Comment: I want to fire for this statement: UPDATE mytable SET comecolumn='some' (i.e. set timestamp to zero in trigger if it is not mentioned in the update statement) I don't want to fire for this statement UPDATE mytable SET comecolumn='some', timestamp=12345 (i.e. don't set the timestamp to zero in the trigger if the update statement already sets it to some value)

Comment: What about `WHEN NEW.timestamp = OLD.timestamp` ?

Comment: I'm afraid this won't do what I described...

Comment: Actually `NEW` defines the entire new row and all its content, so `NEW.timestamp = OLD.timestamp` will be false only if you set a **different** value for `timestamp` in your `UPDATE` statement

Comment: You are right. It does what I need. However I don't understand this: If I have row with timestamp = 5 and I run this statement: UPDATE mytable set timestamp=5 then the trigger doesn't set the timestamp to zero even the condition WHEN NEW.timestamp = OLD.timestamp should evaluate to true (5 = 5). I can't understand why...

Comment: Also I noticed that the trigger does what I need if there is no WHEN condition in the trigger. I'm little confused about how triggers in sqlite works...

Comment: OK, to explain my last two comments: the problem was I didn't give the trigger a name. It seems that then the behaviour of the trigger is "little undefined". When I add the trigger a name the behaviour is as expected.

Comment: @MartinDusek If it works now, why not answer the question and mark as accepted? As a side note: I could not get the original trigger to work, even with name.

Answer (score 4):

The only way to make additional changes to a row in an UPDATE trigger is to execute another UPDATE on the same table afterwards.

The only way to detect whether a column value is changed is to compare the old and the new row values; the trigger does not know which columns actually were mentioned in the original UPDATE statement.

To prevent the trigger from triggering itself recursively, you should restrict it to be triggered by changes of all columns except the timestamp:

```
CREATE TRIGGER clear_timestamp
AFTER UPDATE OF all_the, other, columns ON MyTable
FOR EACH ROW
WHEN OLD.timestamp = NEW.timestamp
BEGIN
    UPDATE MyTable
    SET timestamp = 0
    WHERE id = NEW.id;
END;
```

Answer (score 0):

I think the problem is that in the `SET` statement is expanded to every column, with every column set to the current value in the database. So the original only trigger works, if the current `timestamp` column is `NULL`.

A solution could be to create another trigger that resets the timestamp column to `NULL` before an `UPDATE`.

```
CREATE TRIGGER "set_null"
BEFORE UPDATE ON "mytable" FOR EACH ROW 
BEGIN
UPDATE mytable set timestamp = NULL where rowid = NEW.rowid;
END
```

This way the `NEW.timestamp` is `NULL` if it is not specified in the `UPDATE SET`.

Obviously now a `NOT NULL` constraint cannot be set on timestamp.

Another problem is that trigger recursion must be off when executing a update query:

```
PRAGMA recursive_triggers = OFF;
```

Comment: Now you have a recursive trigger.

Comment: What about PRAGMA recursive_triggers = false ?

Comment: Yes, that is indeed a problem. I tested it and it worked, probably because the trigger recursion is turned off. But I did not think about that.

Answer (score 0):

Here is another way:

```
import sqlite3
conn = sqlite3.connect(':memory:')
c = conn.cursor()
name = {'name':'jack'}

c.execute("""CREATE TABLE Programs (
    id INTEGER PRIMARY KEY,
    name VARCHAR(64) NOT NULL,
    time_added INTEGER
);""")

c.execute("""CREATE TRIGGER program_time_added AFTER INSERT ON Programs
    FOR EACH ROW
    BEGIN
        UPDATE Programs SET time_added =datetime('now', 'localtime') WHERE id = NEW.id;
    END;""")

c.execute('INSERT INTO Programs (name) VALUES (?)', [name['name']])
```